# Get user who had no activity in from last 12 months

Tags: mysql

I want to make SQL that will return users who not performed any points/redeem activity in last 12 months

user_data

```
userId  email               create_date
1       steve@gmail.com     2017-01-05 12:55:00
2       mark_nel@gmail.com  2019-05-15 12:13:00
3       les.born@gmail.com  2018-04-05 03:15:00
```

points_data

```
id  user_id activity_id activity_points create_date
 1        1           1              10 2017-01-05 11:09:00
 2        2           1              15 2019-06-12 09:17:00
 3        2           2              10 2019-08-05 02:55:00
 4        3           1              10 2019-01-05 07:15:00
```

redeem_data

```
id      user_id     redeem_points           create_date
1       2           20                      2019-09-11 02:55:00
```

Result

```
email
steve@gmail.com
```

Comment: Why isn't the `user_id = 3` not in the expected output ? Also, what have you tried so far ? Please edit the question and add your attempted query.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` with a subquery that returns all the users who HAVE had activity in the last 12 months. Then return the ones that aren't matched.

Comment: I tried like

    SELECT user.email FROM user_data AS user 
INNER JOIN points_data AS points ON points.user_id = user.user_id
INNER JOIN redeem_data AS redeem ON redeem.user_id = user.user_id
WHERE  (points.create_date NOT BETWEEN '2018-09-13 00:00:01' AND '2019-09-13 23:59:59') AND
(redeem.create_date BETWEEN '2018-09-13 00:00:01' AND '2019-09-13 23:59:59')

Comment: Combine a query for the [group-wise maximum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) (get the newest record per user) with an additional WHERE clause that limits it to only those that older than 12 months.

Comment: @STEVE001, check my answer, if works for you, do accept and voteup. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` concept to include non matching row from table `user_data` and only select non matching row by removing matching rows using `where id of both tables(points_data,redeem_data) is null`.

```
SELECT u.email
FROM user_data u
LEFT JOIN points_data p ON u.userId = p.user_id AND p.create_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
LEFT JOIN redeem_data r ON u.userId = r.user_id AND r.create_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
WHERE  p.id IS NULL AND  r.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but the distinct clause seems superfluous.

Comment: @P.Salmon, It will return multiple rows of same user if it has multiple points or redeem rows. To get only one email, i added that. You can use `group by email` or `distinct email` to make sure you get only record as user wants only list of emails. Let me know what do you think?

Comment: But your null tests will ensure that you only get 1 row per user anyway..(assuming there are no duplicates in user_data)

Comment: You are right, thank you for pointing out. Is there is any  way i can find out who downvoted me, so I can improve my answer like your point.?

Comment: Ancient but still applicable https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers

Comment: @STEVE001, check my answer, if works for you, do accept and voteup. :)